# How to convert string to Regex

Tags: elixir

I have this code

```
reg=~r/(\d{4}.csv)/
raw="some craxy trashy text blabla 0044.csv"
Regex.scan(reg,raw, capture: :all_but_first)
```

This returns `0044.csv`.

However, I need to load the `~r/(\d{4}.csv)/`  from a database, so I will save it as

```
"~r/(\d{4}.csv)/"
```

This is a string. When I load it to a variable, it will be a string.

How can I pass it to a `Regex.scan`?

Comment: I have seen two of your questions and it seems that you need to enable a lot of custom data transformations that can be customized by users. Have you thought about giving them a small programming language that they can use, and which you can just eval safely? I was thinking something like embedding Lua via [luerl](https://github.com/rvirding/luerl).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [Regex.compile/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#compile/2) or `Regex.compile!/2`

```
iex> Regex.compile("(\\d{4}.csv)")    
{:ok, ~r/(\d{4}.csv)/}
```

You will need an extra backslash for escaping, otherwise you will end up with:

```
iex> Regex.compile("(\d{4}.csv)")    
{:ok, ~r/(\x7F{4}.csv)/}
```

Comment: Upvote for pointing `Regex.compile` out, but you're using `compile/1` and not `compile/2` :)

Comment: @Rightleg there is no `compile/1`, the second argument is optional.